# Is there an easy way to schedule automated imports into CRM?

Tags: dynamics-crm

I have control of a website that automatically accumulates leads.  Another individual would like a system to automatically send new leads (emails/names/phone numbers) to their Dynamics CRM.

Is there an easy/practical way to do this?

I can easily setup an endpoint or latest csv url for CRM to digest, but I don't know if CRM would have a way to accept this automatically?